# Crear otro DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

La estructura de la programacón para ser claro es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el primer public ya estaba, pero al momento de crear el segundo

```
namespace Sistem_Ventas.Areas.Indicadores.Models
{
    public class InputModelRegistrar
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo Servicio es obligatorio.</font> ")]
        public String Servicio { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "<font color='red'>El campo MacroIndicadro es obligatorio.</font> ")]
        public String MacroIndicador { get; set; }
```

me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

osea duplica el Primer DropDownList y los combina, eh puesto esto en

en LIndicador

```
public List<SelectListItem> getTServicio()
{
    foreach (var item in _context.TServicios.ToList())
    {
        _selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.ID.ToString(),
            Text = item.Servicio
        });
    }
    return _selectList;
}

public List<SelectListItem> getTMacroIndicador()
{
    foreach (var item in _context.TMacroIndicador.ToList())
    {
        _selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.ID.ToString(),
            Text = item.Nombre_Indicador
        });
    }
    return _selectList;
}
```

y en Registrar.cshtml.cs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se que mas hacer ya que no entiendo donde esta el error.

Comment: En lugar de imágenes, copia y pega el código. Las imágenes deben usarse para describir errores. Gracias por considerarlo :D

Comment: Lo hice pero sale un error que si es mucho codigo mejor ponga imagenes referenciales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variable de tipo de referencia guardan sus valores apuntando a un solo espacio de memoría (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), por lo que lo que estas haciendo con tus dos métodos en LIndicador es aumentar la lista de valores, en lugar de comenzar una nueva lista. Te sugiero utilices dos variables diferentes para cada lista:

```
public List<SelectListItem> getTServicio()
{
    var _selectListServicio = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in _context.TServicios.ToList())
    {
        _selectListServicio.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.ID.ToString(),
            Text = item.Servicio
        });
    }
    return _selectListServicio;
}

public List<SelectListItem> getTMacroIndicador()
{
    var _selectListMacroIndicador = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var item in _context.TMacroIndicador.ToList())
    {
        _selectListMacroIndicador.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = item.ID.ToString(),
            Text = item.Nombre_Indicador
        });
    }
    return _selectListMacroIndicador;
}
```

Comment: Excelente me suena logico pero tengo este codigo        `        public LIndicador(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }`

Comment: Por qué o para qué necesitas que _selectList sea una propiedad de LIndicador? Según entiendo, incluso pudieras eliminar esa propiedad de tu lIndicador..

Comment: y como lo llamo para lo que es el registro de un dropdownlist                                      `                            @Html.DropDownList("Input.Servicio", new SelectList(Model.Input.TServicios, "Text", "Text"), "Seleccione el Servicio", null)
`, ya que al momento de registrar  me sale error

Comment: KodiakMx apoyame con la duda

Comment: No se si entiendo bien la pregunta, pero veamos. Necesitas crear dos DropDownList: @Html.DropDownList("Input.MacroIndicador", new SelectList(Model.Input.TMacroIndicador, "Text", "Text"), "Seleccione el Servicio", null) y @Html.DropDownList("Input.Servicio", new SelectList(Model.Input.TServicios, "Text", "Text"), "Seleccione el Servicio", null)

Comment: Si exactamente pero cuando pongo la parte de registrar me sale error de :  @Html.DropDownList("Input.Servicio", new SelectList(Model.Input.TServicios, "Text", "Text"),   y no se por que

Comment: Pero qué error te sale?